# replacing a really old bathroom fan?

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

New house and a bathroom fan that doesn't run.  Managed to get the cover off and fan out, everything is rusted, but it still gets power.  Should I replace the whole unit or can I replace just the fan (unclear if I can find a replacement fan?)

[image]

[image]

photos from above (not great access through a trap door in nearby closet ceiling) and below and of fan pulled out of housing , Small flap for the air in the box in the ceiling, can't tell if there are issues with the duct work.

Any ideas appreciated !!

Answer (score 3):

New bathroom fans are inexpensive and easy to install.  You seem to have a good exhaust duct there (would be nice to see the entire path) .. you could clean it while you're working on it.  You have power, you have access from above and below.  It's a replacement job as easy as one can get.

It's hard to imagine repairing a dinosaur fan would be easy or even possible.  It looks larger than most modern fans, so you may need some ceiling repair if you buy a new one.  But my instinct would be to go that way.

Comment: Vent fans come in all sorts of sizes, so it should be possible to find *something* that fits the existing hole reasonably closely, even if it may push too much air for the duct.  Bonus is that the new fan will probably be a lot quieter than the old one.